# iPhone: Exception when implement "Show More" in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am implementing the "Show More" function like the one in AroundMe. In fact I do not have any problems on it until I try to keep all the data in the whole string and pass to the other view later.

When click "Show More" button below code will be called:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[_connection release];
if(controlFlag == 1){

    additionalstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:additionalresponsedata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.additionalresponsedata = nil;
    NSArray* addresultsData = [additionalstring JSONValue];
    [loadingIndicator_2 stopAnimating];
    temp1 = [additionalstring substringFromIndex:4];

   int temp = totalstring.length - 1;// i set break point here

    NSLog(@"%d", temp);
    totalstring = [totalstring substringToIndex:temp];
    totalstring = [totalstring stringByAppendingString:@","];


    int addtotal = [addresultsData count];

    for (int i = 0; i < addtotal; i++){
        //choose a random loan
         //store retailerid   

    }
```

additional string is getting from server and i want to save into total string together each time when user click "Show More".

In my program, the first time click show more, all looking good, but when click the second time, it throws out exception:

```
 -[__NSCFData getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x737f210
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x737f210'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x187a052 0x169ad0a 0x187bced 0x17e0f00 0x17e0ce2 0x178398e 0x1855c6e 0x17a3b6c 0x1822ce8 0xb0cb63 0xb0cad5 0x756b 0xb9ba59 0xb99e94 0xb9aeb7 0xb99e4f 0xb99fd5 0xadef6a 0x133dbbd 0x140a5ea 0x1334298 0x140a16b 0x1334137 0x184e97f 0x17b1b73 0x17b1454 0x17b0db4 0x17b0ccb 0x167c879 0x167c93e 0x1a6a9b 0x21bd 0x2135 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

thanks j

Answer (score 0):

Why are you releasing active "_connection" variable? I don't understand what you are releasing there. Try removing that line. Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: Hutgebdra Thx Sai, that's because in my didselectrowatindexpath the _connection will be inited. It is general implmentation to release connection after finish loading. Anyway I did try your suggestion but still not luck.

Comment: Can you post the "Show More" button code. So that I will try to find out what causing the crash.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. Just bc I forgot to use "retain" in the code.... thx